# How to update my Windows application package in wingetcreate

Tags: cmd, winget

I have a little problem while I want to **update** my package. I'll explain this: I published my package. After that, I waited for 2-3 hours for my packages be in the  [microsoft/winget-pkgs](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-pkgs/) in GitHub. My branch merged successfully, It works on any Windows devices but, I created a new version of my application: v3.6.2. The version that I released it was v3.5.7. So now, I can't publish that version because this error is showing when I execute this cmd command: `wingetcreate update <packageIdentifier> -u https://github.com/YourUsername/yourrepository/releases/download/3.6.2/yourapp.exe --version 3.6.2 -t ghp_YourGithubPersonalAccessTokenWith_public_repo_setting`.

If you want an image, i'll show you the image (My Windows is French btw): [Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNPjA.jpg). But as you can see, the red is the `error` and I tried everything, I searched on Google and didn't find anything that fixed my problem, I tried the examples showed above when you only execute this command: `wingetcreate.exe update` but still the same error message that you can see on [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNPjA.jpg).

So I decided to take the third example but same, without success. Is there a way that could update my WinGet package? Thanks!

I don't know if this could help but I can give you some info: it's inno, the achitecture is `Neutral`.

***IMPORTANT NOTE***:
[FIX HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71504291)
The last answer works but if you type the command `winget search <YourApp>`, it will keep the previous version and if you install, it would install the previous one... How to fix that because it is litteraly **NOT** updating but doing *nothing*.

Comment: Are you wanting to remove 3.5.7 or just publish 3.6.2?

Comment: Just to publish 3.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the way: You take the code that [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71475853/3025856) contains, and add `-s`:

```
wingetcreate update -s <packageIdentifier> -u "https://github.com/YourUsername/yourrepository/releases/download/3.6.2/yourapp.exe|x64" --version 3.6.2 -t <githubToken>
```

It will publish the application on GitHub for verification, in the command prompt you put (replace the sentence in the quotes with your current manifest file):

```
winget validate --manifest "PathToYourManifestShowedInGreenAfterPublishing"
```

When the validation on GitHub is done, it's done and normally it should work.

***NOTE:*** Verification on GitHub can take 2 to 3 hours or even 4 hours. Be patient! (I hope)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard for me to know exactly what the issue is without knowing the contents of the manifest or the metadata of the installer. My gut feeling is that there is an architecture mismatch when trying to match the installer you provided with the existing installer that is currently specified in the existing manifest. To override the detected architecture you can use the '|' symbol followed by the desired architecture. Here is an example:

```
wingetcreate update <packageIdentifier> -u "https://github.com/YourUsername/yourrepository/releases/download/3.6.2/yourapp.exe|x64" --version 3.6.2 -t <githubToken>
```

If that doesn't work for you, I would encourage you to post an issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-create/issues) so we can help you further.

Comment: But wait, why does the package version instead of showing 3.6.2 still show 3.5.7?

Comment: I think it doesn't work. It says that it's validated and pulished but it's still 3.5.7 and if I install my application, it will install 3.5.7...